# Button doesn't work after DataGridView Validating Event

Tags: vb.net, validation, button, datagridview

I have a `Form` with a `TabControl` on it. On one of the `TabPages` is a `DataGridView` with a New- and Delete-`Button` below it. I also have a `Validating-Event` for the `DataGridView`. Inside the `Event` I do some checking. If the conditions are not met I do a simple:

```
e.Cancel = True
Return
```

But after that my Delete-`Button` isn't working anymore. Even if I set a `Breakpoint` right at the start of the `Click-Event` nothing is happening what could that be? I have set the `CausesValidation` to `false` on the `Button`.

**Update**

I need to handle both Events, because the Sum of this DataGridView is compared to another value. The Sum can't be smaller or bigger than the other Value. But the User can enter what he wants as long as at the End the Sum is correct. I can't do that in the CellValidating because as soon as I change a Value the Sum doesn't match anymore

**Update**
I have observerd the following Scenarios where it doesn't work:

1. I change Data in the `DataGridView` and then trigger the `Validating`-Event. It starts working again when I input correct Data and switch `Tabs`
2. I create a new `Row`, trigger the `CellValidating`-Event and after that the DGV `Validating`-Event

Comment: Are you really handling the `Validating` event of the grid or the `CellValidating` event?

Comment: I handle both Events

Comment: Why do you handle both?  Why do you handle `Validating` at all?

Comment: Added additional Info

Comment: So, when your `Button` appears not to work, is it just the `Validating` event that is being cancelled or both it and `CellValidating`?

Comment: It seems to depend on the `Validating` event, if it's only the `CellValidating` the Button still works.